# How to stop MP4 file from stuttering in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player, mp4

Playing an HD MP4 file in Ubuntu stutters using Movie Player or LibreOffice Impress. Interestingly, when using VLC, it plays perfectly smoothly. I have noticed that in system monitor, when playing with any linux tool, it only uses 1 core but when using VLC, it uses all cores equally.

Is there a file format I can convert to that Movie Player/Impress will natively support better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I guess I'm going to answer my own question. It turns out that the .mkv file format is very popular in Linux and is well natively supported. You'll notice that camera applications also use this format. [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) is a great tool to convert your MP4 file to .mkv. Good luck Blaine! :)